# Android, Access Fragment method from separate class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, method-call

I have a **Fragment**:

```
public class CustomFrag extends Fragment{
    ...
    public void refreshList(){
        ...
    }
}
```

I have a separate **Class**:

```
public class SomeClass{
    ...
}
```

I am trying to call `refreshList()` from `SomeClass`:

```
String tagName = "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + 1;
CustomFrag f2 = (CustomFrag)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tagName);
f2.refreshList();
```

But this shows *`Cannot resolve method 'getActivity'`*. If I add to the class:

```
extends Fragment
```

All the warnings go away, but the app crashes, with a null-pointer exception to the `CustomFrag f2 = (CustomFrag)...` line.

I have another fragment, contained within the same parent as `CustomFrag`, and the method call described above works great.

How can I access the `CustomFrag` methods from `SomeClass`? This question (and similar) are asked all over, but most do not have accepted answers, or else have very vague ones that are of little help.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: Temp solution**

I am calling methods that belong to `SomeClass` from within the two aforementioned Fragments. What I came up with is the following:

Within `FragOne`

```
public class FragOne extends Fragment{

    ...

    String tagName = "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + 1;
    CustomFrag f2 = (CustomFrag)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tagName);
}
```

And then:

```
public class FragOne extends Fragment{

    ...

    String tagName = "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + 1;
    CustomFrag f2 = (CustomFrag)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tagName);

    SomeClass obj = new SomeClass(...);
    obj.someMethod(f2);
}
```

Where `someMethod` then can use

```
f2.refreshList();
```

This solves the issue I have been having, but it would still be nice to know a more direct way to access the Fragment's methods via a separate Class.

Further answers that solve this problem are welcome, and will be accepted as solution.

Comment: instead of `extends Fragment` extend `CustomFrag `

Comment: @VenomVendor it still gives me the same NullPointerException

Comment: by using interface you can call refreshList() from your class

Comment: can you post your log.

Comment: Please see question edit, with working temp solution.

Answer (score 7):

***HomeFragment.java***

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static HomeFragment instance;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        instance = this;

        return view;
    }

    public static HomeFragment getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        // do something...
    }

}
```

***AnotherClass.java***

```
public Class AnotherClass() {
     // call this method
     HomeFragment.getInstance().myMethod();
}
```

Comment: This causes memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need to get the activity context of the fragments. You cannot just make up a new class extending a fragment class, without actually instantiating the fragment and associating it with an activity, and hope to get back your activity context from it.

If you wish to use `SomeClass` independent of the Fragment, you can declare a variable to hold the parent activity

`private FragmentActivity mActivity;`

and then in the constructor, you may pass the activity context reference into it.

```
public SomeClass (FragmentActivity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
    ...
}
```

Afterwards, you can call

`mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tagName);`

when you need it within `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Create interface for that

```
public interface Callback{
void refreshList();
}
```

This is your fragment

```
public class CustomFrag extends Fragment implements Callback{
...

new SomeClass().setListener(CustomFrag .this);

@Override
  public void refreshList(){

//do work
 }
}
```

Write your class

```
 public class SomeClass{
 private Callback mCallback;

 public void setListener(Callback callBack){
 mCallback=callBack;
  }
}
```

call Fragment refreshListview from your SomeClass like this

```
mCallback.refreshListView();
```

Comment: Where do I put `new YourClass().setListener(CustomFrag .this);`? and is `YourClass` supposed to be `SomeClass`? Also, what is `activity` in the method? Should it not be `callBack`?

Comment: Your conversation going between fragment and yourClass right? For that this is.

Comment: Edited answer, Please check now